# My anaconda version is 1.9.12 and Python is 3.8.3 but when I want to install tensorflow I get a problem

Tags: python

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
> to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
> - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|3.7.*']
>
> Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.

When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify that.

Comment: how did you try to install tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `TensorFlow` are you trying to install? It looks like you are trying to install an older version of `TensorFlow`.

Try this:

```
conda install tensorflow==2.2
```

This version is supported by Python 3.8.l

Answer (score -1):

open cmd and write  `pip install tensorflow`

or in anaconda prompt write `conda install tenorflow`